# Is less than not working in a SQL query PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL table like this:

```
point     | z_id | ok|
300697.12 | 391  | 1 |
300701.88 | 391  | 1 |
300576.78 | 391  | 1 |
300576.78 | 391  | 1 |
```

and I run this query

```
SELECT MAX( `point` ) as `max`
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `point` < 300701.88
AND `z_id`='391' AND `ok`=1
```

It should return 300697.12, but I get 300701.88, I tried to put the number into '', but I get the same results. Even if I run the query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM `my_table`
WHERE `point` < 300701.88
AND `z_id`='391' AND `ok`=1
```

the 300701.88 result is still there.

My field type for `point` is float(10,2).

Is there a problem with sql considering the number as a text?
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8f995/1)

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table  WHERE point < "300701,88" AND z_id="391" AND ok="1"; this work on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Mysql Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-float.html)

> Floating-point numbers sometimes cause confusion because they are
>   approximate and not stored as exact values. A floating-point value as
>   written in an SQL statement may not be the same as the value
>   represented internally. Attempts to treat floating-point values as
>   exact in comparisons may lead to problems. They are also subject to
>   platform or implementation dependencies. The FLOAT and DOUBLE data
>   types are subject to these issues. For DECIMAL columns, MySQL performs
>   operations with a precision of 65 decimal digits, which should solve
>   most common inaccuracy problems

Clearly `float` datatype is the problem here which is also known as *approximate datatype* which will not store the exact value. This is the reason `float` should be avoided.

Changing the datatype from `float(10,2)` to `Decimal(10,2)` will fix your problem

Here is the [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4fe90/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it stopped working after an update from PHP 5.4. to 5.5. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your are confusing `float()` and `decimal()` data types.  A MotoGP explains, the right type is `decimal()`.  However, you should also be able to express the logic using `cast()`:

```
where point < cast('300701.88' as float(10, 2))
```

This might be useful if you are stuck with the particular definitions in the table.  The idea is to ensure that the values are compared as exactly the same type.